# Display text under overlay item

Tags: c#, android, monodevelop, toast, itemizedoverlay

I am using MonoDevelop for Android with Google maps and overlays.

My question is this: How can I add a brief section of text under each overlay item?

This is the code I normally use to display text:

```
var toast = Toast.MakeText (this, "Test", ToastLength.Short);
```

This works, yet it is placed at the bottom of the map. I am after the same idea, yet I can position the text under each overlay item.

May I please have some help to do this?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I have been given some code to set toast at a given offsetX and offsetY. May I please have some code to actually find the offsets for each overlay item that is drawn as ItemizedOverlay so that I can display toast text under each overlay item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to show toast at top :

```
String text = “example toast text!”;
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

/* Positioning your Toast */
int offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0;
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, offsetX, offsetY);
toast.show();
```

Refer [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-toast-example/) link for more customization of Toast.

Comment: Thanks. For the 'positioning your Toast', how can I get the offsetX and offSetY of an Overlay item? I have more than one Overlay item.

Comment: Can you please advise me on this please?